# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip showing / hiding consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Problem by showing and hiding consecutively a tooltip.

Have a look at this snippet:http://jsfiddle.net/r7GCJ/

```
the input-field shows an tooltip if the number in the tooltip is even.
```

If you fast triple-click the backspace-key (which means '6' is the last char), you will not see the bootstrap tooltip, even though the number is even. 
(Maybe you need one or two attempts)

Anyone an idea how to fix this problem, or whats the problem?

PS: In my 'real code' I have to look up via AJAX if the number is already in a DB, and if so I show the tooltip.

Comment: Try turning animation off on your tooltip. This will speed up the time involved in showing/hiding the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a curious issue. I have found a solution, although I'll admit it's a bit kludgy. Instead of hiding it, I'm destroying it and recreating it whenever I want to show it. I can't reproduce the issue in fiddle anymore.

```
$('#fooInput').keyup(function (e) {
    var $foo = $(e.target);
    if (parseInt($foo.val()) % 2 === 0) {
        // create the tooltip
        $foo.tooltip({
            trigger: 'manual',
            title: 'gerade Zahl!',
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
        $foo.tooltip('show');
    } else {
        $foo.tooltip('destroy');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r7GCJ/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting thing :D. I don't know why but this is non common situation. You can solve this by writing `<input id="fooInput" type="text" />` instead of your code with initial value. You can add another tooltip to say that only numbers are allowed.

Comment: Well, to be honest the code I posted isn't my 'real code'. In my real project, I make an AJAX-Call to check if the number in the input-field is already present and if so, I show a tooltip with an error. Which means your solution wouldn't work in my real scenario. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @goto: Having the same problem, have you found a solution?